# Backbone.js unable to access the router functions?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple implementation of Backbone.js which goes like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
    "/getAcademics": "academics"
        }, 

    academics: function(){
            alert("ok");
    $("#content").append("<div>Academics</div>");
    }
    }); 
var myWorkspace = new Workspace;
});
```

The link in the body is given as -

```
     <a href="#/getAcademics">Academics</a>
```

Though the router routes to the link #/getAcademics but it does not execute the function academics. Any clues as how to rectify this. Am I missing something else.

Thanks

Comment: "What's wrong with my code.." questions may be better served on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you instantiate your router, and before you attempt to use any of its routes, you need to call Backbone.history.start(). This will setup a listener for hash changes and call the correct route functions when needed.

You can find more information here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History